# Uncheck checkbox in Angular 2 ngModelChange event

Tags: angular

We have a form in an Angular 2 app. The form has a checkbox. Under some circumstances, checking the checkbox is illegal. When the user checks the checkbox, we want to show an error message and uncheck the checkbox.

This almost works. In our event handler we check the condition, warn the user and set the checkbox variable back to false. Unfortunately, the checkbox remains checked.

The order of events as we have seen it is this:

1. User clicks the checkbox.
2. Our `checkbox` variable becomes true.
3. Our event handler is called.
4. Alert is shown (using `alert` for now)
5. Alert is dismissed
6. `checkbox` variable set to false by our code.
7. Our event handler finished.
8. **Checkbox is checked in the browser**

   The model (`checkbox`) remains false, but the user doesn't see it. How can I uncheck the checkbox *after* it is actually checked (as opposed to 'about-to-be-checked')?

   Here is a [Plunkr demonstrating the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/9rtPKvw4BunaaHO8gJYL?p=preview).

Comment: hard to tell without code...

Comment: Right. I've added a Plunkr demonstrating the behavior.

Comment: You need to wrap your `this.checkbox=false ` by as `setTimeout`, but why not disabling the input instead of live unchecking it ?

Comment: In this case users are going to wonder why the checkbox is disabled, it's not obvious from the rest of the data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Original answer :

Wrap your `this.checkbox=false`with a `setTimeout` :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' [(ngModel)]='checkbox' (ngModelChange)='onCheckboxChange()'>    Can't be checked
    </label>
    <pre>{{checkbox}}</pre>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  checkbox: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.checkbox = false;
  }
  
  onCheckboxChange() {
    if (this.checkbox) {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.checkbox = false;
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2uoQ8nmTy3dhdApzhetV?p=preview)

### For future readers :

You can find explainations about why this `setTimeout`might be required on this question :

### [Angular 2 - Checkbox not kept in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339450/angular-2-checkbox-not-kept-in-sync/43339577#43339577)

Comment: I thought we got rid of this behavior. I guess not. I'll try this out, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you need to share some code ,but as per description problems seems to be with ngModel to unchecked the checkbox use like this

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="your condition">
```

Comment: I've added a Plunkr to demonstrate the issue