# Angular 4 checkbox state not updated even if model changed

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular2-forms

I know this issue with is still open, but according to this workaround [Angular 2 - Checkbox not kept in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339450/angular-2-checkbox-not-kept-in-sync) it should work as expected, however I still struggle to make it work with my case.

I have the list of permissions which are granted to a role. When the user wants to update a role, I display the form with editable role name and the list of it's permissions as checkbox list. Now, I need to make some of the list items checked, if the role already has a permission from the list.

My form:

```
<tr *ngFor ="let perm of permissions, let i = index">
        <td>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                    name="check-box-{{perm.permission_alias}}"                                            
                    value="{{perm.permission_id}}"  
                    (ngModel)="perm.checked"
                    (ngModelChange)="onSelectFilter($event,perm)"
                    attr.id="check-box-{{perm.permission_alias}}"
                    /> 
            {{perm.permission_alias}}
            </label>                                
        </td>
    </tr>
```

My component:

```
getPermissions(role: Role): void {
    this.permissions = [];
    this.userService.getPermissions().then(perms => {            
        if (role != null) {
            this.permissions = perms;
            for (let rp of role.permissions) {          
                let index = this.permissions.indexOf(this.permissions.find(p => p.permission_id == rp.permission_id));
                if (index >= 0) {  
                     this.permissions[index].checked = true;
                    //this.onSelectFilter(true, this.permissions[index]); not sure if this should be called
                }      
            }
            console.log("before selected perms on update");
            console.log(this.permissions);
        }
        else {
            this.permissions = perms;
        }

    }).catch(this.handleError);
}

   onSelectFilter(selected: boolean, filter: Permission) {
        filter.checked = selected;
        if (this.permissions.every(filter => !filter.checked)) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.permissions.forEach(filter => filter.checked = true);
            });
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why this isn't working, I have no items checked in the list.
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What part isn't working. This code `this.permissions.forEach(filter => filter.checked = true);` looks very weird. You use filter, but ignore the result, as filter criteria you are using an assignment. The `setTimeout` also looks redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works. It will always keep things in sync using 2-way data binding.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
name="check-box-{{filter.text}}"
[(ngModel)]="filter.selected"
attr.id="check-box-{{filter.text}}">
```

If you need to trigger some function on change, use the change event.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
name="check-box-{{filter.text}}"
[(ngModel)]="filter.selected"'
(change)="myCustomFun()"
attr.id="check-box-{{filter.text}}">
```

Updated the same in your [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fw0lBEgbASlCyKj5jE8f?p=preview) from your workaround link

Comment: Got it, the problem was in this line `  value="{{perm.permission_id}}"  `, I needed to remove it. thanks anyways!

Comment: I love this solution, but what I has tried gave me the disappoint result. So solution is that create a `Promise` and `setTimeout` for 200 ms to check the items that were checked after action performed.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the error here is because you are always '**mutating the array**'. When angular does the change detection run, it sees no changes, and the ngFor is not updated. Try this code, look that the only thing I am doing is making a copy of the array before I mutate it.

```
getPermissions(role: Role): void {
this.permissions = [];
this.userService.getPermissions().then(perms => {            
    if (role != null) {
        this.permissions = perms;
        for (let rp of role.permissions) {          
            let index = this.permissions.indexOf(this.permissions.find(p => p.permission_id == rp.permission_id));
            if (index >= 0) {  
                 this.permissions = this.permissions.slice(0) // copy the array.
                 this.permissions[index].checked = true;
                //this.onSelectFilter(true, this.permissions[index]); not sure if this should be called
            }      
        }
        console.log("before selected perms on update");
        console.log(this.permissions);
    }
    else {
        this.permissions = perms;
    }

}).catch(this.handleError);
}

   onSelectFilter(selected: boolean, filter: Permission) {
    filter.checked = selected;
    if (this.permissions.every(filter => !filter.checked)) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.permissions = this.permissions.slice(0) // copy the array.
            this.permissions.forEach(filter => filter.checked = true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've tried to apply your changes but it didn't help. I think the model is ok, because if I display `{{perm.checked}}` in the list label, I can see that some of the elements are true and others are false. The problem is in updating checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [(ngModel)] with boolean variable because check boxes are two way data binding

Comment: Some explanation as to why this qualifies as the solution would be good.