# two-way data binding of input checkbox element

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

My problem goes like this:

I have this array and variable:

```
// the options
public items = [{id: 1, main: true}, {id: 2, main: false}, {id: 3, main: false}];

// the selected option
public selectedItem = this.items[0];
```

and my html looks something like this:

```
<select id="itemOptions"
        name="itemOptions"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.id}}</option>
</select>

<input id="mainItem" 
       name="mainItem" 
       type="checkbox"
       [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.main"
       (ngModelChange)="setMain()" >
```

and the `setMain` function looks like this:

```
setMain() {
  for(let item of this.items){
    //set all items` main to false if they are not the selected item
    if(this.selectedItem.id != item.id){
      item.main = false;
    }
    //if it is the selected item, set it as the main item
    else if(this.selectedItem.id == item.id){
      item.main = true;
    }
  }
}
```

the point here is there must be a main item at all times.
but when I select the main item and uncheck it the function works great and the `main` stays `true`, but the checkbox is still unchecked.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214655/angular-2-checkbox-two-way-data-binding) post and some more but did not found something that look like my case, nor clues for an answer.
As I understand the two-way data binding, when I clicked the checkbox it changed the value of my `selectedItem.main` to false. but then the `setMain` is called and sets it back to true. Why the checkbox doesn't become checked back?

Any way of achieving this would be great :).

note: I don't want to set the checkbox `checked` to true manually. I want to understand why the two-way data binding doesn't handle this case.

Comment: Use check event instead of `(ngModelChange)="setMain()"`

Comment: @SandipPatel tried this as well. didn't work

Comment: can you please provide plunker

Comment: @SandipPatel [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/BX3xnpWFDIJrQkPve5ex?p=preview) is my first plunker ever so I hope I did well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution to your situation**

is put all the code of `setMain` within `setTimeout` :

```
setMain() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        for(let item of this.items){
            //set all items` main to false if they are not the selected item
            if(this.selectedItem.id != item.id){
                item.main = false;
            }
            //if it is the selected item, set it as the main item
            else if(this.selectedItem.id == item.id){
                item.main = true;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-timeout)**

For more detail please check : **[Angular 2 - Checkbox not kept in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43339577/2349407)**

Comment: At least I had the experience of using plunker first time in my life ^.^

Comment: @Dzak ,Still a long way to go , :) , Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as below please check is it that you required?

```
<input id="mainItem" 
name="mainItem" 
type="checkbox"
[(ngModel)]="selectedItem.main"
(click)="setMain($event.target.value)" >

setMain(value) {  
    for(let item of this.items){
        //set all items` main to false if they are not the selected item
        if(this.selectedItem.id != item.id){
            item.main = false;
        }
        //if it is the selected item, set it as the main item
        else if(this.selectedItem.id == item.id){
            item.main = !value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm tried to use your code but its acted the same as mine... care to provide me a working plunker?